# Unity game architecture: Should I create a script for player behavior or use components for game designers to create the character?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in Unity with a team and I have a question about the architecture. Should I create a script to handle the player's behavior or would it be better to create components so that the game designer can create the character using those components?

I feel that by creating everything using components, the GameObject ends up with too many attached components.

Comment: This is not a very fitting question for stackoverflow, because there is no single agreed upon answer.  You may have better results on gamedev.stackexchange.com.  IMO there is a tradeoff between the 2 solutions, where a single script can make it difficult to update behaviour, but too many components can make solutions convoluted.

Comment: Code separation is a good thing so any given script is only responsible for one task. Such as movement or input or updating ui. However it can feel messy when you have 30 things to do what seemed a simple set of tasks. 

Make it. You can always refactor later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question varies depending on the project size, project scale, time, and team composition. And it leans more towards being an opinion rather than a one-size-fits-all solution due to the unique consequences associated with each approach. It is essential to take into account your team's expertise and preferences when making this decision.

Normally I will go for components, but then one day I saw something like this: [Scary example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZvS.png) . I was jaw dropping and designer crying.

So ideally, if you know how, I would suggest having one script that uses Scriptable Objects to Add or swap in and out for different behaviors. And add your own editor script to make it compact and easy for designers to work with. One example would be the [Feel package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/feel-183370). e.g. [Feel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaj2W.png)

But that would take alot of work for the programmer and development time. So you need to consider the scale of the project before you make this move.